I am getting feign.codec.DecodeException: Error while extracting response
I am getting Following error when I am calling DeleteMapping to my AuthService from my Customer Service
feign.codec.DecodeException: Error while extracting response for type [class com.nrv.customer_service.response.DeleteResponse] and content type [application/json]
.
.
.
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Error while extracting response for type [class com.nrv.customer_service.response.DeleteResponse] and content type [application/json]
.
.
.
Caused by: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `com.nrv.customer_service.response.DeleteResponse` (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
.
.
.
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.nrv.customer_service.response.DeleteResponse` (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)

AuthCleint
@FeignClient(name = "AUTH-SERVICE")
public interface AuthClient {

    @DeleteMapping("/api/auth/{id}")
    DeleteResponse deleteAnAuthUser(@PathVariable String id);
}


Basically When I am deleting a Customer I also want to delete a Auth user from my Auth Service.
For the rest of the methods Like Post and Put it is working perfectly fine but when I want to delete the Auth User I am getting the above error. DeleteResponse.java class is also identical in both of the services.
DeleteResponse.java
@Data
public class DeleteResponse {
    private String message;
    private LocalDateTime localDateTime;

    public DeleteResponse(String message) {
        this.message = message;
        this.localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
    }
}

CustomerServiceImpl class Delete Customer Method:
    @Override
    public APIResponse deleteCustomer(String customerId) {
        Customer customer = repository.findById(customerId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Customer with ID: " + customerId + " not found"));
        repository.delete(customer);
        deleteCustomerInAuthService(customer.getEmailId());
        // Deleting Customer from Auth Service
        logger.info(CustomerLogMessage.CUSTOMER_DELETE.getMessage(), customer.getCustomerId());
        return new APIResponse("Customer Deleted With ID: " + customer.getCustomerId());
    }

    public void deleteCustomerInAuthService(String email) {
        logger.info("User Deleted In Auth service With Email: {}", email);

        try {
            DeleteResponse deleteResponse = authClient.deleteAnAuthUser(email);
            System.out.println(deleteResponse);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error deleting user in Auth Service: {}", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

I also tried adding @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class) & @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class) in my DeleteResponse class inside the Customer Service (Where I am receiving data from Auth Client), but it is still getting the error.
As you can see with using try catch I am able to make the operation work but Still, why am I getting such error?

Your DeleteResponse doesn't have a no-args constructor and thus Jackson cannot create an instance. Either add a no-args constructor or provide an @JsonCreator annotation on the constructor to inform Jackson to use that constructor.
